# How do I open a new console window for a Visual C++ console application?

Tags: c++, console, window

What I want to do is something like this:

```
ConsoleWindow1.Print("1");
ConsoleWindow2.Print("2");
```

When I run the program, two console windows pop up and one gets printed with 1 and the other gets printed with 2. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I see, to write a console that prints argument given to exe, and write another application that call both with different arguments, I didn't try but may be you can open two by WIN32 functions, see [How to Open Console Window in a Win32 Application](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/)

Comment: but daniel has asked for a console application not Win32 application.

Comment: Ok, than I see only the first way I offer

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to do is modify another console application. Right now the log is printed to the only console window, and there's a lot of messages so you can imagine it's pretty messy. Rather than comment out the lines I don't need, some of which are useful in certain situations, I want to open a new console window to display the log info I DO need all the time.

Comment: not the answer to your question, but you can write log to text file and open that file in the end ...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I need to see the data in real-time :).

Answer (score 1):

For console based application there can be only one console per process. You can start two processes and then do some sort of IPC to coordinate with each other

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but inter-process communication and multi-threading in general is beyond my current programming abilities. I think I'll try and convert the current console application into a library of some sort, since the only output is a log.